# Solving systems of differential equations with complex solutions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a system of differential equations.

$$\dot{x} = 5x+10y, \dot{y} = -x-y$$

In an attempt at a solution I obtained

$$\mathbb{z} = C\begin{equation}
     \begin{bmatrix}
         3+i \\
         -1
        \end{bmatrix}
  \end{equation}e^{(2+i)t} + 
     \begin{bmatrix}
         -i+3 \\
          -1
        \end{bmatrix}
  e^{(2-i)t}$$

Now I need to sketch some trajectories, so this guy is not very useful to me

Now the second term on the right is a complex conjugate of the first,
I need to get this into something real. If I work with the first term on the right I get

$$\begin{equation}
     \begin{bmatrix}
         3+i \\
         -1
        \end{bmatrix}
  \end{equation}e^{(2+i)t} = 
     e^{2t}\begin{bmatrix}
         3cost-sint \\
          -cost
        \end{bmatrix} +
  ie^{2t}\begin{bmatrix}
         cost+3sint \\
          -sint
        \end{bmatrix}$$

How do I proceed?

I am not really seeing it at the moment, if you post an answer could you please explain how to get this into a real form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** You need to use only one of the eigenvalue and the corresponding eigenvector. As you have simplified the expression:
$$\begin{equation}
     z = \begin{bmatrix}
         3+i \\
         -1
        \end{bmatrix}
  \end{equation}e^{(2+i)t} = 
     e^{2t}\begin{bmatrix}
         3\cos t-\sin t \\
          -\cos t
        \end{bmatrix} +
  ie^{2t}\begin{bmatrix}
         \cos t+3\sin t \\
          -\sin t
        \end{bmatrix} = u(t) + i v(t).$$
The general solution in the case of **complex eigenvalues** is given by $z = c_1 u(t) + c_2 v(t)$. For clarification please have a look at [this course material from MIT](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/unit-iv-first-order-systems/matrix-methods-eigenvalues-and-normal-modes/MIT18_03SCF11_s33_7text.pdf) or at [Paul's online notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/ComplexEigenvalues.aspx).

Comment: That theorem in the notes has made my day. Thanks incognito :)